# Modifying session through simple variables

Tags: php, variables, session

I'm running into a strange issue on my iPage hosted version of my website. When logging into my system, `$_SESSION["id"]` contains the User ID of the logged in user. Somewhere else on my site I am doing something like this to retrieve the ID of a page:

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    // Do something with the $id.
}
```

However, this actually seems to change the value of `$_SESSION["id"]`. I tried doing the following to confirm this:

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    echo $_SESSION["id"]; // Prints e.g. 1
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    echo $_SESSION["id"]; // Prints e.g. 5 when URL contains ?id=5
}
```

This doesn't happen when running my website on my local LAMP environment. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to remedy it?

**Edit**: The whole problem can be re-created using this code on my webhost:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["id"] = 1;
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    echo $_SESSION["id"];
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    echo $_SESSION["id"];
}
```

Thanks,
Jonathon

Comment: Strange. Are you sure there isn't any other code that's causing the issue? Are the files on your localhost exactly the same as the files on your server?

Comment: Since it happens after setting `$id`, the problem must be this variable then, do you not use it anywhere else?

Comment: Sounds like `$id` is a reference, created with `$id =& $_SESSION['id'];`

Comment: Yep I'm sure there's nothing else causing the issue and no, `$id` has not been created as reference. See my updated question